# Unable to connect to local computers in WAN of DD-WRT router.P2P networking not enables

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wan

I have Dlink DIR600 router and I upgraded to DD-WRT recently.

We 7 students share an internet connection via wireless router.

all 7 laptops are assigned an IP by router

Problem is we are not able to ping each other and not able to look up each other in network places.

In short, peer to peer networking is not enabled.
I have explored all possible options in DDWRT control panel but couldnt find such setting.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be two possible different problems - firstly ping is turned off on many OSes - so might not show up

Network places needs you to, iirc be in the same workgroup - you may wish to test accessing shares with //ipaddress/sharename instead - if that works, check your networking settings.

Comment: I am not worried about pinging. Accessing shares through IP names is not working. Actually i want to install a network monitor and shaper such that real time download and upload statistics can be seen. And for this, the monitoring agents should be on each laptop and should be able to communicate..

Answer (score 0):

Some routers (not sure if DD-WRT does this or not) provide a facility called `Wireless Isolation`, `Network Isolation Mode` or `Cafe mode` or something similar.

This prevents wireless clients from a) communicating with each other, and b) communicating with the wired LAN.  This is most often used for public hotspots, like in cafes, airports, etc.

Make sure that this is turned off.

Comment: AP Isolation is found under the Basic Wireless Settings/Advanced.  Turn it off.